# how implement resize uicollcectionview

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

[image]

how can i implement 
The user will be able to show more of the videos by dragging up the holder part (==) or the video thumbnails area.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your collection on something like a pull view:
https://github.com/matej/MBPullDownController